# Parse.com orderByDescending doesn't work

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have the following code:

```
PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[innerQuery whereKeyExists:@"image"];
[innerQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
[query whereKey:@"post" doesNotMatchQuery:innerQuery];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    // comments now contains the comments for posts without images
}];
```

But the orderby doesn't work. Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: It's working... but you order the "POST" ... and after thay... you make a query on "Comment" with `doesNotMatchQuery`... So, will get only a few records from "Comment" without any Order

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. It should be matchQuery instead of doesNotMatchQuery.

Comment: Just to clarify - you want a list of Comment objects, but you want the Comment objects ordered by the 'createdAt' field of the associated Post object, right?